# Access Denied on a Ubuntu Desktop shared folder from Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, samba

I'm using Windows 10 version 1511 as a client, and Ubuntu 15.10 Desktop with Samba 4.3.9 as server. If I create a shared folder in Virtualbox on the Windows machine and try to get access from this machine - everything works perfectly. And if it's the two computers connected to the network i get "access denied" message on Windows side. Is it possible to resolve?

Comment: You're not clear as to which side is getting the access denied message. Also ensure permissions are correct.

Comment: on Windows side. Permissions are automatically set by Nautilus, when i share folder in GUI. I also created and enabled smbpasswd user with same name as in windows and ubuntu

Comment: In the username box of the Windows credentials window when trying to access the smb share, enter `hostnameofubuntumachine\username` and then the password. For example, `UBUNTU-VM\foobar`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest my problem was related to another WORKGROUP in the network. Now with another name everything works on Ubuntu Server.